# Steps in the proof of the corollary of fundamental theorem of calculus in Wikipedia

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, derivatives

I am unsure on a specific step in the proof of the corollary of FTC from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). Suppose $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on the interval $[a,b]$. Wiki used the fact that $G$ define as $$G(x) = \int_a^x f(x) \;dx$$ is an antiderivative of $f$ to show that $$F(a)+c = G(a) \tag{1}$$ for some constant $c$. However, in wiki's proof of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, we only concluded that $G$ as defined above is an antiderivative of $f$ on the interval $(a,b)$. Since $G$ might not be an antiderivative of $f$ on the point $a$, how can we use the property of antiderivative differ from each other by a constant to conclude equation (1)? Is there any other proof of FTC that shows $G$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on point $a$ and $b$?

Thank you so much in advance for answering this! It has bother me for a while now and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Continuity of $G$ and $F$ forces the statement to be true at $a$ and $b$ if it is true in all of $(a,b)$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Do you mean the statement $F(a) + c = G(a)$ or the statement that $G$ is an antiderivative of $f$? Even if $G$ is continuous at point $a$, I still don't know if $G$ is differentiable, which I think is a requirement for $G$ to be antiderivative of $f$ at point $a$?

Comment: $F(a)  + c = G(a)$ is the statement. It isn't really meaningful to say a function is an antiderivative at a point, since the derivative at a point necessarily involves the function values in a neighborhood of that point. To put it another way, we don't say that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ at $a$ if it happens to be true that $F'(a) = f(a)$. Rather, we say that $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ if there is some interval $(a,b)$ where $F'(x) = f(x)$ at every point in that interval.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I see, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, we can use the continuity of $G(x)$ on $[a,b]$ to continuously extend the domain of $F(x)$ to include $a$!

By the first part of the fundamental theorem, we know that $G(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$ on $(a,b)$ and that $G(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Thus, while wikipedia doesn't specify the domain of the antiderivative $F(x)$, we should assume that it is at least defined as an antiderivative of $f(x)$ on the interval $(a,b)$ (we know that this much is possible since $G(x)$ exists). The argument that wikipedia presents then works for the interval $(a,b)$: $F'(x)-G'(x)=f(x)-f(x)=0$ on $(a,b)$ so $F(x)-G(x)$ must be some constant $c$ on $(a,b)$. We can then use the fact that $G(x)=F(x)+c$ on $(a,b)$ and the fact that $G(x)$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ to conclude that $\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)$ must exist (if this limit did not exist, the relationship $G(x)=F(x)+c$ on $(a,b)$ would make $G(x)$ discontinuous at $a$). We then define $F(a)=\lim_{x\to a^+}F(x)$ and note that this gives us $G(a)=F(a)+c$.

This is a great detail to notice and take issue with! The way the article as written is not clear on this point.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems to resolve my confusion. I think this is also the point that @eyeballfrog is making.

Answer (score 0):

While Brian Ransom's answer goes into detail on what I said in my comment, I'd like to add a supplemental answer addressing a confusion in the OP regarding the question of whether $G$ is an antiderivative of $f$ at $a$.

The idea of a function being an antiderivative at a point isn't really meaningful. There are plenty of functions $F$ and $f$ that have a point $x$ such that $F'(x) = f(x)$, but we wouldn't consider that to mean $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ at $x$.  For example, taking $F(x) = e^{x-1}$ and $f(x) = x$, we have $F'(1) = f(1) = 1$, but clearly there is no meaningful sense in which $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$.

The reason for this is that the derivative fundamentally involves function values in some neighborhood (i.e., open interval) containing $x$. Thus, for $F$ to meaningfully be an antiderivative, we want $F'(x) = F(x)$ for all $x$ in this open interval, not just at $x$. This is also why the hypothesis states continuity on $[a,b]$ but differentiability only on $(a,b)$. Differentiability isn't well-defined at $a$ and $b$ because any open interval containing $a$ or $b$ must necessarily contain points outside $[a,b]$, and we aren't assuming anything about its behavior outside of $[a,b]$.